# Creating a barcode bytewise

Tags: java

I am currently working on a piece of legacy code that I inherited. **The current Java version is 6, but this will change in the next few weeks to Java 7.** I think I might have been working on it for too long as I get the impression that it can be made much more readable as I have many byte-wise operations, but cannot find a way to do so.

Do any of you have suggestions on how to improve readability on the following method?

(The class has some more methods of very different setup, however, not much more readable. Since this method can be understood and refactored on its own, I separated it from the class.)

```
/**
 * Creates the barcode bytewise and writes it on the page referenced in the
 * barcodeData object.
 *
 * @param barcodeData {@link objects.BarcodeData}
 * @throws ConverterRuntimeException
 */
public void addBarcode2of5(BarcodeData barcodeData) throws ConverterRuntimeException {
    try {
        IAfpCmd cmdBpg = barcodeData.getPage().findFirstAfpCommand(SfRecordType.BPG);

        CmdDef cmdBbc = new CmdDef(SfRecordType.BBC);
        CmdDef cmdBog = new CmdDef(SfRecordType.BOG);

        ByteData data;

        cmdBpg.addAfpCmd(cmdBbc, true);                                                // Begin Bar Code Object

        cmdBbc.addAfpCmd(cmdBog, true);                                               //   Begin Object Environment Group

        data = new ByteData(new byte[0], 0);
        data.append(ByteConvUtil.int2u2Bytes(0x0343));            // Triplet 43
        data.append(ByteConvUtil.int2u1Bytes(1));
        data.append(ByteConvUtil.int2u2Bytes(0x084B));            // Triplet 4B
        data.append(ByteConvUtil.int2u2Bytes(0));
        data.append(ByteConvUtil.int2u2Bytes(barcodeData.getPageResolution().getXResolution().getResolutionInPelsPerInch() * 10)); // Auflösung in X-Richtung
        data.append(ByteConvUtil.int2u2Bytes(barcodeData.getPageResolution().getYResolution().getResolutionInPelsPerInch() * 10)); // Auflösung in Y-Richtung
        data.append(ByteConvUtil.int2u2Bytes(0x094C));            // Triplet 4C
        data.append(ByteConvUtil.int2u1Bytes(2));
        data.append(ByteConvUtil.int2u3Bytes(barcodeData.getPageResolution().mmX2pels(297))); // 297 mm X in pels (gedreht)
        data.append(ByteConvUtil.int2u3Bytes(barcodeData.getPageResolution().mmY2pels(210))); // 210 mm Y in pels (gedreht)
        cmdBog.addAfpCmd(new CmdDef(SfRecordType.OBD,
                data.getCompleteDataArray()), true);                               //     Object Area Descriptor

        data = new ByteData(new byte[0], 0);
        data.append(ByteConvUtil.int2u2Bytes(0x0117));            // Repeating Group 1
        data.append(ByteConvUtil.int2u3Bytes(0));       //   0 mm X
        data.append(ByteConvUtil.int2u3Bytes(0));    // 0 mm Y
        data.append(ByteConvUtil.int2u2Bytes(0));  // 0° gedreht
        data.append(ByteConvUtil.int2u2Bytes(0));       // "
        data.append(ByteConvUtil.int2u1Bytes(0));
        data.append(ByteConvUtil.int2u3Bytes(0));
        data.append(ByteConvUtil.int2u3Bytes(0));
        data.append(ByteConvUtil.int2u2Bytes(0));
        data.append(ByteConvUtil.int2u2Bytes(0x2D00));
        data.append(ByteConvUtil.int2u1Bytes(0));
        cmdBog.addAfpCmd(new CmdDef(SfRecordType.OBP,
                data.getCompleteDataArray()), true);                                 //     Object Area Position

        data = new ByteData(new byte[0], 0);
        data.append(ByteConvUtil.int2u2Bytes(0));
        data.append(ByteConvUtil.int2u2Bytes(barcodeData.getPageResolution().getXResolution().getResolutionInPelsPerInch() * 10)); // Auflösung in X-Richtung
        data.append(ByteConvUtil.int2u2Bytes(barcodeData.getPageResolution().getYResolution().getResolutionInPelsPerInch() * 10)); // Auflösung in Y-Richtung
        data.append(ByteConvUtil.int2u2Bytes(0xFFFF));
        data.append(ByteConvUtil.int2u2Bytes(0xFFFF));
        data.append(ByteConvUtil.int2u2Bytes(0));
        data.append(ByteConvUtil.int2u1Bytes(0x0C));    // Interleaved 2of5
        data.append(ByteConvUtil.int2u1Bytes(0x01));    // Keine Prüfziffer
        data.append(ByteConvUtil.int2u1Bytes(0xFF));
        data.append(ByteConvUtil.int2u2Bytes(0xFF07));  // Schwarz
        data.append(ByteConvUtil.int2u1Bytes(0xFF));
        data.append(ByteConvUtil.int2u2Bytes(barcodeData.getPageResolution().mmY2pels(6))); // 6 mm Höhe in dots (intern)
        data.append(ByteConvUtil.int2u1Bytes(1));
        data.append(ByteConvUtil.int2u2Bytes(0xFFFF));
        cmdBog.addAfpCmd(new CmdDef(SfRecordType.BDD,
                data.getCompleteDataArray()), true);                                 //     Bar Code Data Descriptor

        cmdBog.addAfpCmd(new CmdDef(SfRecordType.EOG), true);                         //   End Object Environment Group

        data = new ByteData(new byte[0], 0);
        data.append(ByteConvUtil.int2u1Bytes(0x80));
        data.append(ByteConvUtil.int2u2Bytes(barcodeData.getPageResolution().mmX2pels(barcodeData.getxPos()))); // Position X mm in dots (intern)
        data.append(ByteConvUtil.int2u2Bytes(barcodeData.getPageResolution().mmY2pels(barcodeData.getyPos()))); // Position Y mm Y in dots (intern)

        data.append(barcodeData.getKontrollNr().getBytes("IBM500"));
        cmdBbc.addAfpCmd(new CmdDef(SfRecordType.BDA,
                data.getCompleteDataArray()), true);                                  //   Bar Code Data

        cmdBbc.addAfpCmd(new NamedAfpCmd(SfRecordType.EBC, null), true);               // End Bar Code Object
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        throw new ConverterRuntimeException("Ein Fehler ist beim Erstellen des Barcode aufgetreten: \n\r:" + ex.getMessage());
    } catch (ConversionException ex) {
        throw new ConverterRuntimeException("Ein Fehler ist beim Erstellen des Barcode aufgetreten: \n\r:" + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: A better measure of "too long" is number of local variables rather than actual LOC.  By that measure this code really isn't a red flag just based on the sheer size of the method.  As others have noted, most protocol interface code tends to blow up like this.

Answer (score 6):

When interfacing with 'library' code, especailly when the library is a Java representation of some low-level interface, it is always somewhat ugly. What you see as having readability problems is true, but it's not your fault (mostly).

In circumstances like this, you have to transcode the data in one format, to another, and that other format is highly structured, and specialized. The only way for the code to make sense is if you have the specification for that other API in front of you, or know it really well. In cases like that, I always find it best for the code to represent the specification as much as possible. In this case, I think it does....

... this is even true for the 'magic numbers'. Normally magic numbers are 'bad', and your code is full of them.... but, if the specification contains things like: *... Repeating group consisting of xxa - 3 bytes, xxb - 3 bytes, xxc - 2 bytes, xxd 2 bytes, .....* then you really are doing things 'OK'.

In general, in these cases, the best you can accomplish is to contain the ugliness in a single wrapper library that does the transformation for you, and does not leak the ugliness out.

There are three things I think you can improve:

1. Do not reuse any variables. Specifically, `data` should be:

   ```
   ByteData dataOBD = new ByteData(new byte[0], 0);
   dataOBD.append(....);
   .....
   cmdBbc.addAfpCmd(new CmdDef(SfRecordType.OBD,
           dataOBD.getCompleteDataArray()), true); 


   ByteData dataBPP = new ByteData(new byte[0], 0);
   dataBPP.append(....);
   .....
   ```

   This way you can move things around a bit more, and you are guaranteed that a later refactor of the code won't mess things up.
2. You have special cases for `BBC` and `BOG`. I would change the code:

   > ```
   >     CmdDef cmdBbc = new CmdDef(SfRecordType.BBC);
   >     CmdDef cmdBog = new CmdDef(SfRecordType.BOG);
   >
   >     cmdBpg.addAfpCmd(cmdBbc, true);                                                // Begin Bar Code Object
   >
   >     cmdBbc.addAfpCmd(cmdBog, true);                                               //   Begin Object Environment Group
   > ```

   to just:

   ```
   cmdBpg.addAfpCmd(new CmdDef(SfRecordType.BBC),true); // Begin Bar Code Object
   cmdBbc.addAfpCmd(new CmdDef(SfRecordType.BOG), true); // Begin Object Environment Group
   ```

   which is consistent with the rest of the code.
3. The special `\n\r` newline in the exceptions.... are you sure it is necessary? And, if it is, why are you not using the system property or a constant for it. Also, you are not adding the actual stack to the exception (just the message). Your exception class `ConverterRuntimeException` should be able to take a `Throwable` constructor argument, and it should look like (note the `ex` at the end):

   ```
   throw new ConverterRuntimeException("Ein Fehler ist beim Erstellen des Barcode aufgetreten: " + NEWLINE + ex.getMessage(), ex);
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your input. About Number 3 i was pondering very similar thoughts, as the ex.getMessage() more often than not only shows very little useful information (NullPointerException ==> null). I will try and convince the library owner to change or enhance the library to allow for better exception handling.

Comment: @ChristianKullmann - You can always use the 'ugly-but-effective `RuntimeException re = new ConverterRuntimeException(....); re.initCause(ex); throw re;`

Answer (score 3):

Just three short points I want to get done with:

#### Instantiating CmdDef:

> ```
> CmdDef cmdBbc = new CmdDef(SfRecordType.BBC);
> CmdDef cmdBog = new CmdDef(SfRecordType.BOG);
> //and the other similar calls.
> ```

While this code Is nice and easy to read, you have quite many of these `CmdDef(SfRecordType.*)` instantiations. You might want to think about changing instantiation of `CmdDef` to a factory design to abstract that away from this methods responsibility. Creating a new instance could then look like this:

```
CmdDef cmdBbc = CmdDefFactory.createWith(SfRecordType.BBC);
```

While you're at it, you could extract the specific behavior of each record type to a new class derived from CmdDef, which would become an interface / abstract class. This helps with decoupling your application and makes unit-testing easier.

#### Naming

While we're at these... `cmdBbc` and the like are rather uninformative and confusing names.
Same goes for the likes of `IAfpCmd` and `SfRecordType`. They are making me wonder:

> "Sf" - Maybe ScienceFiction?
> "Bbc" - probably not British Broadcasting Corporation, but *what then?*
> "IAfp" - *confusion ensues*

It may be, that you have some strange hungarian notation like naming convention at your workplace. If that's the case, I recommend you change it. Because this is all more confusing than enlightening. And let's be honest, a few chars more or less in the source code - Who cares about that in today's "everyday business application"?

#### Exception handling:

As you mentioned, that migration to Java 7 is scheduled, you should definitely have your separate Exceptions packed into a multi-catch:

```
catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | ConversionException ex) {
    //handle, rethrow, whatever ;)
}
```

You called that wrapper exception `ConverterRuntimeException`, but you are then adding a throws-declaration for it. This leaves two possibilities:

1. This is not a RuntimeException, but **should** be. You maybe extended the wrong Exception-Class. The throws declaration is wrong and should be removed.
2. This is a RuntimeException, but **should not be**. Instead you should extend a checked Exception and rename your custom exception.

Style points for the catching of specific exceptions, though ;)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed analysis. I should have mentioned before that i am working in the domain of AFP print stream creation. AFP is a technology developed by IBM using many, many three-letter-abbreviations for document layout elements i.e. record types.  
That means e.g. BOG == BOG (inside the AFP domain) which resolves to "Begin Object Group".

Comment: Exception Handling:  I must admit I am still a bit wobbly on the proper exception handling styles but i had a gut feeling that this was not quite correct. That being said I don't understand what you mean by "You called that wrapper exception ConverterRuntimeException, but you are then adding a throws-declaration for it.". If I use the ConverterRuntimeException to wrap the thrown exceptions in it (in one way or another) I would need to throw it, wouldn't I? In case i am a complete idiot right now, please point me to some further info. Sorry :-/

Comment: @Christian I am here referring to that whole discussion of Checked vs Unchecked Exceptions. A RuntimeException (and her Subclasses) are not required to be caught, as they tend to happen with unrecoverable errors, that are supposed to run up the whole Call-Stack. That is also why they do not require a throws declaration. OTOH there's checked Exceptions. About these, the caller can usually do something (or is **expected** to do something.) That's why you **need** to add a throws-declaration for them, so the caller **has to** wrap them into a try-catch. For more, come visit me in [chat] ;)